# how to properly format checkboxes. (best for jquery and crossbrowser)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've seen lots of ways. And I remember I had some problems make it crossbrowser and retrieve checkbox state with jQuery.

from html `checked` to `checked="true"` and `checked="1"` and even `checked=checked` or `checked="yes"`

now... once for always. What is the best way for crossbr. check/uncheck and make jquery finally work 
getting/changing state?

Comment: any best way to write checkboxes and retrieve/change state with jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually very simple and jQuery has just confused everyone.

- In HTML use either `checked` with no value or `checked="checked"`.
- In XHTML (although it's very unlikely you should actually use it), use `checked="checked"`.

In JavaScript, the checkedness of a checkbox is represented in every scriptable browser in the simplest possible way: a Boolean property. So, given the HTML

```
<input id="foo" type="checkbox" checked>
```

... you can get its checked state as follows:

```
var checkbox = document.getElementById("foo");
alert(checkbox.checked);
```

... and set it as follows:

```
checkbox.checked = false;
```

**That's it.**

jQuery provides the advantage of being able to handle multiple elements in one call. In jQuery 1.6 and later you do this with `prop()`. In earlier versions, use `attr()`.

```
$("#foo").prop("checked", false);
```

Don't try and deal with the attribute directly: simply use the `checked` property and you'll never go wrong. This goes for pretty much all attributes when dealing with HTML.

Answer (score 3):

The `checked` attribute is a [boolean attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.3.4.2). It takes one value, and one value only: `checked`. This has [not changed in HTML 5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attributes).

```
checked="checked"
```

If you are writing HTML (as opposed to XHTML) then you may provide just the value.

```
         checked
```

In JavaScript, the `checked` **property** can be assigned the values `true` or `false`. Any other value will be converted (e.g. `"checked"` is a string, so it converted according to the rules for converting strings and becomes `true`).

Answer (score 2):

I usually do this to check if it's checked and i never had problems:

```
$('#chk').click(function(){
    $('#show').toggle($(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

and this to check/uncheck it (jquery 1.6 or higher):

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    var chk = $('#chk')
    if(chk.is(':checked')){
        chk.prop('checked', false);
    }else{
        chk.prop('checked', true);
    }

});
```

To check or uncheck with jquery you should always use prop() since it's specifically targeted at properties.

in pure html the correct way i think is (of course omit checked if you don't want the checkbox to be checked):

```
 <input id='chk' type='checkbox' checked value='1'>
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TTWVd/2/

Comment: nice! never used .prop() before. i'll make more researches. thanks for the demos

Comment: you should use prop because 'checked' (like 'selected') is a property and not an attribute

Comment: @Nicola: No, `checked` certainly is an attribute, and is reflected in a Boolean property in the DOM. jQuery has seriously confused people with this stuff, and actually it's just so simple: see @Quentin's answer.

Comment: @Nicola: Also, if you're just dealing with one checkbox, skip jQuery and just use the couldn't-be-simpler `checked` property. Your first function for example, would be much simpler, more readable, more compatible and more performant as `$('#chk').click(function() { $('#show').toggle(this.checked); });`. Likewise the second function would be better as `$('#button').click(function() { var chk = $('#chk')[0]; chk.checked = !chk.checked; });`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm concerned, so long as the `checked` attribute exists the box should be ticked, even if you proceed to set the value as false, `checked="false"`, [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Ilmv/MUxvL/).

However, I usually use `checked="checked"`, and I've never had an issue with cross browser inconsistencies.

However, the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial/Input_Controls#Checkboxes_and_Radio_Buttons) suggests using boolean values as strings (it that makes sense). However with my above example, in FireFox 5 `checked="false"` still checked the element.

Comment: Thanks. yes, but jquery removing checked makes it just like `checked=""` that is translated by the browser like it's still checked. in some cases :)

Comment: Okay fair enough, can you give a specific example of this problem, including browser version and jQuery version.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, the property is a [boolean](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_checked.asp). In HTML, the property will be ["checked"](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_checked.asp) (this can also be shown in [W3 standards](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.4) -- note the (checked) (booleans in HTML will generally be their [property names](http://www.pubpixel.com/article/18/what-are-html-xhtml-boolean-attributes-and-how-do-i-use-them) can't find the W3 ref. on that one, but it is true)).